# Vanishisng vaccum Feynman diagrams in $A-B-\phi$ scattering model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, correlation-functions

Question data given below:

Let us consider the  −  −  model that describes 3 real scalar fields ,  and  governed
by the following action
$[, ,] = ∫ ^
4  (ℒ_ + ℒ_ + ℒ_ + ℒ_{})$

$
ℒ_
[] =
\frac{1}
{2}
_
 ^ −
\frac{1}
{2}
_^
2
^
2$

$ℒ_[] =
\frac{1}
{2}
_
 ^ −
\frac{1}
{2}
_B^
2
^
2$

$ℒ[] =
\frac{1}
{2}
_
 ^$

$ℒ_{}[, ,] = −
\frac{1}
{2}
(_ ^
2 + _ ^
2
) $

In this exercise, we shall determine the 4-point function

$ℳ = ⟨0| ((_4
) (_3
) (_2
) (_1
)) |0⟩$
in terms of Feynman diagrams through path integral expressions.
It is known that
$ℳ =
\frac{_ℳ}
{_0}$

where $_ℳ$, $_0$ are given by the following path integrals

$_ℳ = ∫ Φ (_4
) (_3
) (_2
) (_1
) ^
{}$

$_0 = ∫ Φ ^
{}$
and where
$Φ ≔   $

denotes integration over classical field configurations of all three fields.

The question is how to show through diagrams or algebric path integral in the position space that two (actually three) vaccum diagrams that recieved by expanding $Z_ℳ$ and $Z_0$ up to order 2 in $g_A$ and $g_B$, are vanished when we expanding $ℳ$ to second order?
(Vaccum diagrams are diagrams that including connection of the propogator to itself and not to an external legs, such as "2-tadpoles")